# How to implement borrow flag in C

Tags: c

How to calculate borrow flag by subtracting two 8 bit numbers ?

I found this borrow flag description but I still can't understand how to do it?

> The carry (borrow) flag is also set if the subtraction of two numbers 
>   equires a borrow into the most significant (leftmost) bits subtracted.

I think I need one-liner. Because calculating using loop is big bottleneck. Would be nice to see explanation how borrow flag works.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a loop. The key phrase there is "most significant" bits, not all bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a - b` is exactly equivalent to `a + (-b)`, and indeed that's how it's often calculated in hardware.  Therefore, the *borrow flag* is really equivalent to the [*carry flag*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag).

In your case, the value of the carry flag is equivalent to the value of the 9th bit of your result.

Comment: So if I'm implementing emulator I need to implement just carry flag handling ? Even with SUB instruction ?

Comment: That not really correct, because if you calculate 1 - 1 then according to answer it should be same as 1 + (-1) = 1 + not(1) + 1 and if you calculate the last expression (in binary) you will see that carry flag set (16 bit for words), but in really it is not. So 1 - 1 != 1 + (-1). You should in real calculate 1 - 1. You could check it using the following code in x86: mov eax, 1; sub eax, 1 -> carry not set. mov eax, 1; add eax, -1 -> carry set

Comment: @mblw Yup, you're right...except there's some missing useful information that's been overlooked here...In a SUB operation, and strictly speaking for the x86 architecture, a carry in the corresponding addition means NO BORROW in the SUB operation. So carry in ADD a, -b means no borrow in SUB a, b for b > a. But...implementing this logic programmatically is a little confusing and produces weird results so in my implementation I just used "unsigned b > unsigned a" to set the borrow (aka carry) flag in a sub operation. You can even do "if (a - b) < 0 then set carry" and that will also work.

Answer (score 5):

If you are subtracting `x - y`, borrowing (carry-in) occurs when `y > x` with both `y` and `x` considered as unsigned quantities.  Therefore you ought to be fine with the C code:

```
b = (unsigned)y > (unsigned)x;
```

If you want the way a processor would actually compute this, then

```
x7 = x >> 7;
y7 = y >> 7;
r7 = (x - y) >> 7;
b = (~x7 & y7) | (y7 & r7) | (r7 & ~x7);
```

Here's truth table for 2-bit numbers:

```
 x     y     r   b
00    00    00   0
00    01    11   1
00    10    10   1
00    11    01   1
01    00    01   0
01    01    00   0
01    10    11   1
01    11    10   1
10    00    10   0
10    01    01   0
10    10    00   0
10    11    11   1
11    00    11   0
11    01    10   0
11    10    01   0
11    11    00   0
```

You can check out e.g. the SBA instruction in [the HC12 Reference](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/CPU12RM.pdf).  This uses exactly the expression for `b` given above.

Comment: So you getting all most significant bits. Can you explain all variants then you set borrow flag. It's hard for me to understand last logic expression.

Comment: Maybe you mean (~x7 & y7) | (y7 & r7) | (~y7 & x7); ?

Comment: I added some detail and a reference. Hope this helps.  Intuition is not a good guide here.  This definition is what you need for a "subtract with borrow" instruction to work for 16-bit and larger operations with the 8-bit wide register.